# express js response returning object as string

Tags: node.js, express

Why express js returning object as String.
i have array type object  const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; but when i return this object to calling code its returning as string not object , how to return an object in response.send?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
   res.send(cars );
  
})
```

Thanks,

Comment: try ```res.json(cars)```

Comment: i also tried that still same issue

Comment: What's your http client header?

Comment: i tried with application/json and without , still same ,thats why i posted question here

Comment: Not that it's your issue, but you don't require the async there

Comment: HTTP responses are strings. If you want to return a string representation of an object, you'd need to tell express to convert it for you (that's what res.json does)

Comment: @KevinB - Note that `res.send()` will automatically convert to JSON if what you're trying to send is a Javascript object (see [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send)).  There is no requirement to call `res.json()` specifically.  Express perhaps wasn't always this way, but it has been for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can't send a live Javascript object over http.  You have to convert it to something that your underlying transport is capable of sending and then the receiving end can read that format and convert it into a live Javascript object in the recipient's Javascript engine.

So, with http and Javascript objects, that usually means you send a JSON representation of the object which is a string since JSON is a text format specifically designed for serializing/deserializing Javascript objects.

By default, `res.send(cars)` will see that you're trying to send a Javascript object (an array in this case) and will serialize it to JSON, set the `content-type` of the response to `application/json` and send it.  The recipient then needs to recognize that content type and parse the JSON back into its object form.

In your specific example, you only show the server-side code which is likely properly sending JSON as the response.  You will need the client-side code to recognize that content-type and parse it into a live Javascript object again.  If you show the client-side code of this transaction, we can help more specifically with that.

For example when using the `fetch()` interface from browser-Javascript, you would need to execute something like:

```
let response = await fetch(someURL);
let obj = await response.json();
```

to parse the JSON response into a Javascript object.